# List all Azure servicebus subscriptions in a ServiceBus namespace

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I am migrating my project from the `WindowsAzure.ServiceBus` to the new `Microsoft.Azure.Servicebus` NuGet package.

The problem is that I cannot find a way to list all my current topics/subscriptions in my servicebus namespace.

This is the piece of code I used before with the old NuGet package:

```
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString("ServiceBusConnectionString");

foreach (var topic in await namespaceManager.GetTopicsAsync())
{
    foreach (var subscription in await namespaceManager.GetSubscriptionsAsync(topic.Path))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
foreach (var queue in await namespaceManager.GetQueuesAsync())
{
    //do something
}
```

Edit: The latest version has support for listing all topics, subscriptions and queues.

```
var managementClient = new ManagementClient("ServiceBusConnectionString");

foreach (var topic in await _managementClient.GetTopicsAsync())
{
    foreach (var subscription in await _managementClient.GetSubscriptionsAsync(topic.Path))
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Microsoft.Azure.Servicebus` This is the next generation Service Bus .NET client library that focuses on `queues & topics`.You could get more information about `Microsoft.Azure.Servicebus` from [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet).

If you need management opersations, the new client won't provide it. I recommend that you'd  better use Management library or wait till a replacement package for NamespaceManager is out.

If Management library is possible, you use the following 
demo code to list the subscription .For more details about how to use the Management Library, you could refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104773/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-azure-service-bus-namespace-from-within-net/48106623#48106623).

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(@"authpath");
var azure = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(credentials)
            .WithDefaultSubscription();
var sbNameSpace = "service bus subscription";
var resoureGroup = "resourcegroup";
var topicName = "topicName"
var servicebus = azure.ServiceBusNamespaces.GetByResourceGroup(resoureGroup, sbNameSpace);
var topic = servicebus.Topics.GetByName(topicName);
var subscription = topic.Subscriptions.List();
```

Comment: Are you saying that it is not possible to list queues and topics using this new library? I haven't tried using this library but I don't think that's correct.

Comment: @GauravMantri We could get the [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/tree/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus) here. I don't find list topics function. If any you could commnet here, I will update the answer.

Comment: You're right Tom. Here's the Github issue around this: https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65.

Comment: There will be a lilghtweight library/package to replace what `NamespaceManager` has provided with the old client. Details [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65#issuecomment-338874419). It will work with a connection string rather than AAD credentials required by the management library.

Comment: @SeanFeldman Thanks for your Info. If is issued, would mind sharing the lilghtweight library/package link?

Comment: @TomSun it's not available yet, but will be shortly.

Comment: @SeanFeldman If any update about that you could comment here. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I will wait till the new `NamespaceManager` is available.