# Microsoft.ServiceBus.NamespaceManager - Managed Service Identity(MSI)

Tags: c#, azure, servicebus, azure-managed-identity

Has anyone managed to implement Managed Service Identity with NamespaceManager?

I have used the below example for QueueClient but could not seem to find anything for NamespaceManager.

```
MessagingFactorySettings messagingFactorySettings = new MessagingFactorySettings
{
    TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedServiceIdentityTokenProvider(ServiceAudience.ServiceBusAudience),
    TransportType = TransportType.Amqp
};

messagingFactorySettings.AmqpTransportSettings.EnableLinkRedirect = false;

MessagingFactory messagingFactory = MessagingFactory.Create("sb:/namespace",
messagingFactorySettings);

QueueClient queueClient = messagingFactory.CreateQueueClient("testqueue");
queueClient.Send(new BrokeredMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Has anyone managed to implement Managed Service Identity with NamespaceManager?

Unfortuntly, according to [Managed Service Identity (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity), we **can't** use the .NET Framework client NamespaceManager object within a managed service identity.

> management operations that change the namespace topology are initially supported only though Azure Resource Manager and not through the native Service Bus REST management interface.
>
> you **cannot** use the .NET Framework client **NamespaceManager** object within a managed service identity.

If you want to operate servicebus namcespace, I recommand that you could the use the [Azure fluent SDK Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent/) and [Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent/) to do that. For detail demo code, you could refer to this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104773/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-azure-service-bus-namespace-from-within-net).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I will look into this tomorrow. This would mean using 2 libraries to accomplish a single task.

Comment: Hi Tom, I still need to implement Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.

Comment: Do you have any link on how MSI can be used with the above?

Comment: You could refer to [What is Managed Service Identity (MSI) for Azure resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-service-identity/overview#try-managed-service-identity) and [Managed Service Identity (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity) to get more information.