# how to create a topic programatically in azure portal using .NET core

Tags: asp.net, azure, .net-core

Below is the code in .NET framework.what is the equivalent code in .net core using microsoft.azure.servicebus library

```
var namespaceManager = NamespaceManager.CreateFromConnectionString(ServiceBusConnectionString);
        if (!namespaceManager.TopicExists(topicName))
        {      // Configure Topic Settings.
            var td = new TopicDescription(topicName);
            td.MaxSizeInMegabytes = 1024;
            td.DefaultMessageTimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);

            namespaceManager.CreateTopic(td);
        }
```

Comment: See whether this link helps: https://www.example-code.com/dotnet-core/azure_service_bus_create_topic.asp

Answer (score 0):

You also could get this [issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet/issues/65) from Azure SDK github.  Please refer to  Azure Service bus [github](https://github.com/Azure/azure-service-bus-dotnet) to get more information.

> The standard way to manage Azure resources is by using Azure Resource Manager. In order to use functionality that previously existed in the .NET Framework Service Bus client library, you will need to use the Microsoft.Azure.Management.ServiceBus library. This will enable use cases that dynamically create/read/update/delete resources.

Currently, we could use the Azure fluent SDK Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent and Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent to do that. About how to create auth file please refer to another [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104773/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-azure-service-bus-namespace-from-within-net/48106623#48106623).

```
var azureCredentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile("authfile paht"); // or different way
var azure = Azure
               .Configure()
               .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
               .Authenticate(azureCredentials)
               .WithDefaultSubscription();
var sbNameSpace = "service bus name space";
var resoureGroup = "resourcegroup";
var serviceBusNamespace = azure.ServiceBusNamespaces.GetByResourceGroup(resoureGroup, sbNameSpace);
serviceBusNamespace.Topics
                   .Define("topicName")
                   .WithSizeInMB(1024)
                   .WithDefaultMessageTTL(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
                   .Create();
```

Comment: can you please be more clear like what does azure credentials mean?

Comment: Sorry for missing the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104773/is-there-any-way-to-create-a-azure-service-bus-namespace-from-within-net/48106623#48106623), I also updated my answer.

Comment: what is client and key in that authfile?

Comment: @bhargavporapu You need to registry an Azure AD application, for more information please refer to  this [toturial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal)

Comment: can we create a topic in azure namespace without using azure resource management?

Comment: Based on my knowledge, currently **no**.

Comment: can we create subscription for a topic in azure namespace without using azure resource management? if yes how

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If we want to management(create/list/update) the servicebus resources. Currently we need to use azure resource management. If use https://github.com/Mossharbor/AzureWorkArounds.ServiceBus is possible, you could have a try